# javascript var in nested function as event

Tags: javascript

I have this script which work (not in the if part) to check a picture dimension. the picture have to under 300x300 and this script always return false (even for 100x100 picture)

```
function validate_dimention(fileName) {
    input = document.getElementById("profilepic");
    file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var width;
    var height;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(pic) {
        image.src = pic.target.result;
        image.onload = function() {
            width = this.width; //panjang
            height = this.height; //lebar
        }
    }
    if (width <= 300 && height <= 300) {
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log(width);
        console.log(height);
        return false;
    }
}
```

the console log always return both as undefined (so the code have no syntax eror),, is there a way so width equals to //panjang and height equals to //lebar??

Comment: Or another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: It's not possible to `return` a result based on information only obtained by an asynchronous event. The event won't actually occur to set the information until after the `return` has already provided a value.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski sorry but dont really get your idea.. the full code was in https://codeshare.io/jscript,, can't I check it before submit it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `onload` is an event, and is asynchronous. It will be called after the image loaded. Just move the condition inside the `onload` function to solve this. But, because of that asynchronous call, you'll not be able to `return` any value directly. You'll have to use a callback, where you'll do the code depending on the result:

```
function validate_dimention(fileName, callback) {
    input = document.getElementById("profilepic");
    file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var width;
    var height;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(pic) {
        image.src = pic.target.result;
        image.onload = function() {
            width = this.width; //panjang
            height = this.height; //lebar
            if (width <= 300 && height <= 300) {
                callback(true);
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

// And you call it that way :
validate_dimention(fileName, function (result) {
    // Do whatever you want, using result as the result of your function. It 'll be either true or false.
});
```

Comment: Well that'll get the `console.log()` calls working, but overall the function still won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: I just saw that, editing my answer

Comment: @NathanP. I've move it and still not working... :(

Comment: @Vins check my update answer, and also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) pointed by users in the comments

Comment: @NathanP. hm.. looks like I still dont really get it,, i've change my code to like this https://codeshare.io/likeThis ,, and still failed to return true on 100x100 picture

Comment: @NathanP. the console.log(calback) ??

Comment: @Vins To answer your question, make a function to handle the `onchange` event and call the `validate_dimention` the way I showed you. Also, document yourself about callbacks and asynchronous calls.